# Pasar un valor por href a otra vista en codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Soy nuevo en **Codeigniter** y  tengo una tabla con botón editar y otro eliminar, necesito pasar las variables del `row->id_categoria`, `row->name`, `row->desc_cat` a otra vista y luego editarla en ella, es decir, necesito que llene los **input** del formulario de la otra vista con **href**. Adjunto código para ser más claro. ¿Tal vez deba primero pasarlos a un controlador primero?

**Tabla de la vista:**

```
<table id="categorias" class="table table-hover table-bordered" >
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center">ID</th>
    <th class="text-center">Categorías</th>
    <th class="text-center">Descripción</th>
    <th class="text-center">Editar-Eliminar</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


   <?php
if(!empty($procat)){
foreach ($procat->result() as $row) {
    ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo  $row->id_categoria;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->desc_cat;?></td>

<th class='text-center' style=' background-color: white;  min-width: 110px; text-align: center;'>
<a class="btn btn-info" href="<?php echo base_url () ?>ccategoria/editcat/<?php echo $row->id_categoria ?>"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-edit" title="Editar"></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="<?php echo base_url () ?>ccategoria/elimcat/<?php echo $row->id_categoria ?>"><i class="fa fa-lg fa fa-shopping-cart"title="Entradas"></i></a></th>
```

Tengo  que pasarlo a la otra vista si se puede o primero al controlador `ccategoria/editcat` para después pasarlo al modelo o no se si es mejor por **ajax**.

**Formulario de la otra vista llamada `vedit_categoria`:**

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-title-w-btn">
            <h3 class="title">Actualizar Categoría</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>ccategoria/editacat/?>">
            <p>Modifique el nombre de la categoría de productos.</p>
            <label class="control-label">Nombre:</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="categorie-name" id="categorie-name" value=""  readonly>
             <label class="control-label">Descripción:</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="categorie-desc" id="categorie-desc" value=""   required>
             <button type="submit" name="edit_cat" class="btn btn-info" id="edit_cat">Actualizar categoría</button>    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>ccategoria?>" class="btn btn-info">Volver al Listado</a>
             </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existen distintas maneras de realizarlo, entre las cuales se encuentran:

Por el `href` enviarlos como parámetros `$_GET`.

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="<?= base_url ('ccategoria/editcat?cat='.$row->id_categoria) ?>">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-edit" title="Editar"></i>
</a>
```

Por el `uri` obtenerlos como `segment`.

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="<?= base_url ('ccategoria/editcat/'.$row->id_categoria) ?>">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-edit" title="Editar"></i>
</a>
```

Dentro de tu **controller** antes de mostrar la otra **view** lo que realizaras será lo siguiente:

Para el metodo `$_GET`:

```
public function editcat()
{
    // Obtener el parametro $_GET por metodo de codeigniter que hace xss_clean
    // Utiliza el helper form
    $data['id_categoria'] = $this->input->get('cat', true);
    // O obtener el parametro por metodo tradicional
    $data['id_categoria'] = $_GET['cat'];
    // Aqui ya puedes poner la carga de tu otra vista y mandar los datos
    $this->load->view('tuvista', $data);
}
```

Por el método `uri`:

```
public function editcat()
{
    // Obtener el parametro por URI
    $data['id_categoria'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
    // Aqui ya puedes poner la carga de tu otra vista y mandar los datos
    $this->load->view('tuvista', $data);
}
```

Puedes ver la documentación de `uri` en el siguiente enlace: [URI Class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)

Answer (score 0):

No sé si entendí bien, pero pareciera que esa tabla, que en realidad es un datatable, fuese como una ventana modal y quieres que el registro o la fila que se seleccione del datatable (la ventana/formulario modal) pase a un formulario para poder editarlo. Si esto es así, no estás tratando distintas vistas, permaneces o estás en una sola vista, una vista puede contener ene distintos formularios, y éstos últimos mostrarse cuando sea necesario interactuando con botones y/o otros elementos pero para CodeIgniter permaneces en una misma vista.

Y si todo lo anterior es así, no te compliques de más y simplemente usa JavaScript o JQuery para pasar datos de un formulario html a otro.

No leí completamente tu código por lo que lo anterior no aplica. Pero te estás complicando, considero que pudieses trabajar los formularios con las funciones `hide()` y `show()` de JQuery, mostrar por defecto el formulario correspondiente, cuando necesites realizar una búsqueda ocultas un formulario y muestras el formulario de búsqueda y así... de esta manera, no tienes que estar haciendo un request http para devolver al usuario al formulario principal con los datos que seleccionó en otro formulario.

Pasas los datos de un formulario a otro mediante JavaScript o JQuery.